# atinout - bash will hang after sending AT command to analog USB modem

Tags: bash, usb-modem

I have downloaded the latest version of atinout, an application to send AT commands to a analog USB modem.
http://atinout.sourceforge.net/

Now, I try examples I found at the given website, but no one will work.
The problem is, that after sending a AT command to the modem, my bash will hang after returning the echo of the given AT command, an OK and that's all. My bash is hanging.

the simplest example is to hang up an incoming call:

```
echo ATH | atinout - /dev/ttyACM0 -
```

I will geht ring, ring, OK Many empty lines in the bash or an output file but the command will not hang up the call.

Is here someone who can help?
Thanks

Comment: `expect` can easily handle asynchronous devices like modems,  read `man expect`. Also, see my answer about groups: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361381/write-to-device-and-capture-response/1361393#1361393

Comment: Thank you for your hint but with the rights is everything OK so far I have seen.  
The hanging problem  not only occures with atinout but also with cu and socat. only minicom will work properly.  
After I exit minicom with or without resetting the modem, atinout, socat and cu will then work.

so the question ist what does minicom different than cu or socat.